# TextMesh Pro text will not change via script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I cannot seem to change my TextMeshPro value via script.
In my inspector I have a TextmeshPro object named Countdown. I have a script named GameController which is attached to this.

My script then sets the string value of Countdown to Hello but it does not work.

**GameController**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour {

    public TextMeshProUGUI Countdown;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        Countdown = GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI> ();
        Countdown.text = "Hello";   
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

In the inspector there is a field for TextMesh but  I cannot drag the CountDown object to this for some reason, could that be the issue?

[image]

Comment: TextMesh and TextMeshPro are 2 different things.  Can you show us a screenshot of this object in the inspector?

Comment: Added image above.

Comment: It appears to me the `Countdown` object is a prefab. Is that right?

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if its because Countdown is a broken prefab link?  Try removing the link to the prefab and give it a try? (You can do this in the GameObject menu at the top)

Comment: No that was a mistake, I have changed it back to a regular TextMeshPro object but it still has the same issue.

Comment: Also, since the GameController is on the said Countdown object, with the `TextMeshProUGUI` attached, there is no need for a public field. Let me know if I have missed something here.

Comment: @bolkay yea, even though he is still calling GetComponent on it the text isn't changing.  Also, as a public field he should still be able to drag that component into the field slot and change it.  Neither are working that is the problem.

Comment: @Ninja2k Your newest screenshot shows a null error can you show us that error?  Sometimes a null reference error, can cause other problems.  This could also be an issue with the TextMeshPro in your project, can you try this in a new project?  (Making a script that just changes what TMPro components say while running)

Comment: It says Object reference not set to an instance of an object for the line Countdown.text = "Hello"; –   And I have the same issue in a new project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that you are using a regular TextMeshPro object, and in your code your looking for a TextMeshProUGUI, simple mistake. change code to:

```
public class GameController : MonoBehaviour {

    public TextMeshPro Countdown;

    // Use this for initialization
        void Start () {
    //you shouldnt need to get component the editor should take care of this for you when 
//you drop it since you have the object set to TextMeshPro and not just GameObject
            Countdown = GetComponent<TextMeshPro> ();
            Countdown.text = "Hello";   
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update () {

        }
    }
```

the only way to make a TextMeshProUGUI object is to add it through a canvas. in your scene when you just add a TMP it will be Regular TMP which your "countdown" is. you can tell because it uses the TMP script not the TMPUGUI script.